# To avoid pattern inside quotes using python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to match a multi line string str as follows,

```
call fun (TP$NULL, 
    ERROR_CODE,
    PROG_ID || 'Password Incorrect, Please try again') /*END*/
```

I want to process this string with out missing anythings (ie, spaces, tab & newline)

I tried get it by using comma which separate three arguments

```
re.search (r'(\s*call\s+fun\s*\()(.+),(.+),(.+)(\).*)', str, re.DOTALL).groups

('call fun (', 'TP$NULL, ERROR_CODE', " PROG_ID || 'Password Incorrect", " Please try again'", ') /*END*/')
```

see the comma inside quotes in the third argument creates problem.

When I am trying the regex below,

```
re.search (r'call fun \((.+),(.+), (.*\'.*,.*\'.*)\)' , str, re.DOTALL).groups()
```

above case is working but below string str2 is not working.

```
call fun (TP$NULL, err, PROG_D)
```

I tried negative look ahead as follows, but no luck,

```
re.search (r'call fun \((.+),(.+),(?!\'.+\')(.+)\)' , str, re.DOTALL).groups()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you likely just want the first 2 groups to not be greedy, e.g. using your previous to last version:

```
>>> for g in re.search (r'call fun \((.+?),(.+?),(.*)\)', str2, re.DOTALL).groups():
...     print(g)
...
TP$NULL
err
PROG_D


>>> re.search (r'call fun \((.+?),(.+?),(.*)\)', str1, re.DOTALL).groups()
('TP$NULL', ' \n    ERROR_CODE', "\n    PROG_ID || 'Password Incorrect, Please try again'")
```

should cover both presented cases to an acceptable state

Comment: Thank you!. It works. I was making things complex.:)